# What is the fastest way to iterate through a list of features?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have written a QGIS plugin and it iterates through all features in a layer using provider.select() and compares geometry.  The problem, the plugin is very slow.  If there are 114 features in a shapefile and it needs to iterate 80 times then it will have to repeat the code 9120 times.

How can I speed up the iteration process?  Should I store all features in a list and then iterate thru the list?  Store all features in a memory layer (not sure what that is yet)?

Thanks

Ed

Comment: Maybe you could add little more information what you are doing.

Usually you speed spatial stuff by limiting date. For an example it is useless to compare geometries if they are more than 2km apart each other if you are calculating which geometries intersect.

QGis Api for  QgsVectorDataProvider.select gives you option to limit selection by attributes or rectangle

Comment: The plugin searches all features connected to a selected line.  It does this by comparing upstream coordinate to downstream coordinate.  If the distance between the coordinates is less than a tolerance than it will add the feature to a list and repeat the search for the newly selected feature.  So I can't have a fixed rectangle but...

Comment: You just gave an idea.  Instead of iterating through all features each time, I could set a selection buffer around my upstream point and only iterate thru those features.  Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? An upstream or downstream trace?  Having a better idea of your actual goals will help people point you in the right direction for the entire process, not just a single step.

Comment: I wrote a plugin that picks all features upstream of a selected line.  I am finished with the first version.  The only issue I was having was the length of time to iterate thru all features, which after reading Simplexio I realized I could greatly improve the iteration by using a spatial selection.  The plugin will be called Flow Trace and will hopefully be available in the Qgis Plugin repository.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are solving a Graph problem (e.g network connectivity) using the wrong approach. Iterating 80 times over 114 (effectively a linear scan *per edge hop*) is not adequate and is a sign that your algorithm could be optimized. I will go out on a limp and guess that after your reach each edge, you are scanning through *all* the features to figure out which ones are connected, and you do that for every edge. What you want to do is built a connectivity graph once and then traverse that.
If you give us more details about you are trying to do, perhaps we can steer you to a better approach.

Comment: Ragi, I am no longer scanning thru all features and I have finished the first version.  http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/flowTrace/

Comment: @GreyHippo Have you gotten around to updating this plugin for QGIS 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similiar last year with SQL. I had network with several sinks and sources and pipe direction didn't matter.

First i did SQL table #tree |source_id|target_id| (start point over start point or end point...), #closed table |id| and #reached table |id|. All id are pipes unique id

i inserted closed pipe id into #closed and first pipe id's from source to #reached table, then loop over  #tree  table until i didnt have anything to insert into #reached table. It is little bit slow way to do it but it works, only thing you need is tree

```
DECLARE @closed varchar(50)
SET @closed = '23'
DECLARE @root varchar(50)
SET @root = '42'
```

-- add all sources to reached 
insert into #reached values ( @root ) -- substitute root id as needed
while ( @@rowcount > 0 ) begin
insert into #reached (id ) 
select  distinct child as id
    from tree e 
    join #reached p on p.id = e.parent collate database_default
    where 
    e.child collate database_default not in ( select id from #reached )
    AND e.child != @closed  AND  e.parent != @closed
    -- change to :  e.child not in #closed
    UNION
    select  distinct parent as id
    from tree e 
    join #reached p on p.id = e.child collate database_default
    where 
    e.parent  collate database_default not in ( select id from #reached )
    AND  e.parent != @closed  AND  e.child != @closed

end

That solves which pipes are connected to source or sources . It dosen't support several closed id , but it should be easy to fix.

Can't remember original author but i found base script from internet

Comment: I am using shapefiles